# Counting the number of rows of having one column values are matching

Tags: shell, file, awk

I want to calculate the number of rows having same value in first column but different in second column using either shell script or awk.
For e.g. File consists of

```
400.00     1234
400.00     2134
400.05     4314
400.05     9766
```

Hence count should be 2,2,......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `uniq`'s counting option:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' inputfile | uniq -c
      2 400.00
      2 400.05
```

This assumes that in the first column all identical values appear sequentially. If this is not the case you can sort the input numerically before piping into `awk`.

Comment: `I want to calculate the number of rows having same value in first column but different in second column` I don't think your awk|uniq does it.

Comment: @Kent The problem appears a bit underspecified. Apparently my proposed solution does what it should, since it was accepted.

Comment: Suppose at column value 400.00 there are two records are present and I want to create a file consists of these two records.. similarly how should I create file for value 400.50 ,.......

Comment: @Sachinshinde I think that's a different problem, so I suggest you ask a new question; be sure to specify exactly what the input is and what output you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just `awk` alone would suffice for this, no other utilities needed,

```
awk '{unique[$1]++}END{for (i in unique) print i,unique[i]}' fileabc
400.05 2
400.00 2
```

Comment: `I want to calculate the number of rows having same value in first column but different in second column` ;-) I think the $2 should be somehow checked as well, what do you think?

Comment: @Kent: OP's input doesn't justify it, :) not sure though

Answer (score 0):

This probably works:

```
sort <file> | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c
```

---

Breakdown:

```
sort | uniq # Eliminates duplicate entries and sorts things for uniq calls
```

Next:

```
 awk '{print $1}' # Extract the first column
```

Finally

```
uniq -c # Count the number of entries with a identical values in column 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk one-liner will calculate it for you, no matter if your input file is sorted or not:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=($0 in b)?0:1;b[$0]}END{for(x in a)print x":"a[x]}' file
```

I changed your input a bit, to contain some dup values:

```
kent$  cat f
400.00     1234
400.00     1234
400.00     1234
400.00     2134
400.05     4314
400.05     9766

kent$  awk '{a[$1]+=($0 in b)?0:1;b[$0]}END{for(x in a)print x":"a[x]}' f
400.05:2
400.00:2
```